# Traffic shaping with PPP: which external device should I use?

Tags: networking, traffic-shaping

I have a dual-homed device running Debian acting as my home router, and I'm following [these instructions](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Traffic_shaping) to get `fq_codel` usefully working with my VDSL connection.  I know the instructions refer to Gentoo but the principles are the same.

I have these interfaces:

- **eth0**: external interface connected to VDSL modem
- **ppp0**: decapsulated traffic from `pppd`
- **eth1**: internal interface

My question refers to this line in the linked script:

```
$tc qdisc add dev $ext handle ffff: ingress
```

Should I use **eth0** or **ppp0** as the value of `$ext` when creating the ingress IFB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly `ppp0`, since that's the thing you want to shape.

`eth0`, if directed to a DSL modem (not router) directly, will either remain unused (merely a transport for `ppp0`), or it could also be a configuration channel to the modem itself.

Some modems have interfaces to query DSL signal quality and other such data. But that's local networking/monitoring, not internet traffic, so it should not be included in the shaping efforts.

It might be different if `eth0` was connected to a switch, and a DSL router just one of many devices used on that line, but then you would most likely not see a `ppp0` device on the box (that's on the router directly then) and the question would not come up...

If `eth0` is connected to an antique hub so you have `ppp0` and also other devices using `eth0` for regular networking ... there is no way to shape that.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, thanks!  My eth0 is connected directly to the modem so I guess ppp0 is the way to go.